# HTML table cells overlapping on Blackberry

Tags: html, css, blackberry

I have the following HTML code:

```
<table><tr>
    <td>Search: </td>
    <td>'.GetCategoryDropdownList().'</td>
    <td>for: </td>
    <td class="input">
        <input class="header-right-search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search by         Book Name, Author, Module Code, or Module Name" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
    <td><input type=submit value="GO" class="yellowhighlightbutton" /></td>
</tr></table>
```

where "GetCategoryDropdownList()" just returns the HTML for a simple dropdown menu.

This table displays fine in all web browsers (including on android/iphone/etc), with each table cell nicely spaced, but on Blackberry the cells end up overlapping.

Do you know why this is happening or any way to fix it?

Thanks

GetCategoryDropdownList() is

```
function GetCategoryDropdownList()
{
    $query = sprintf("SELECT %scategorylist.* FROM %scategorylist", dbprefix, dbprefix, dbprefix);
    $catlist = DbQuery($query);
    $catselect = '<select class="header-category-select" name="category_select">';
    foreach($catlist as $cat)
    {
        if($cat['Code'] == 'catAll')
        {
            $catselect = $catselect.sprintf("<option class=\"header-category-option\" value=\"%s\" selected=\"selected\">%s</option>",$cat['Code'],$cat['Name']);
        }
        else
        {
            $catselect = $catselect.sprintf("<option class=\"header-category-option\" value=\"%s\">%s</option>",$cat['Code'],$cat['Name']);
        }
    }
    $catselect = $catselect.'</select>';
    return $catselect;
}
```

All it does is make a dropdown menu, which displays correctly on every platform except blackberry.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give the **GetCategoryDropdownList()** code? Have you also set the correct headers for displaying in a mobile website? For blackberry browser you can use

```
<meta name=”HandheldFriendly” content=”True” />
```

Check it out: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6176/HTML_ref_meta_564143_11.jsp

Comment: added that code. i haven't added that meta tag, but i'm not completely sure what it does.

Comment: What it does is that it shows the browser it's handheld friendly so the browser has to show it also that way. Just try it!